# Will proper settings of Mac Paths help my pyinstaller 'no module named..' related fail

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I am running python 2.7 on Mac (Canopy installation) and Windows (PythonXY installation) and am trying to package an app on the Mac platform
using pyinstaller.  I have already packaged the application on the windows platform successfully but am having troubles on the MAc.

The main problem appears to be that pyinstaller is not finding all the needed modules.  Originally I was having problems because PYTHONPATH 
had been set in .profile which was not being seen because .bash_profile also existed.  After fixing that problem there were still some modules 
that can not be found, but I am having a problem determining where they might be located (or even if that IS the problem).

When I run pyinstaller on my script I get the following output:

```
geosm421:nctsutil robertclement$ pyinstaller NCTSU.py
1910 INFO: wrote /Users/robertclement/Dropbox/Code/python/NCTSutil/NCTSU.spec
2462 WARNING: You are running 64-bit Python: created binaries will only work on Mac OS X 10.6+.
If you need 10.4-10.5 compatibility, run Python as a 32-bit binary with this command:

VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes arch -i386 /Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python

6767 INFO: UPX is not available.
7900 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
8973 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
9076 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
9933 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
11606 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
12272 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
12382 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
23315 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with /Users/robertclement/Dropbox/Code/python
23316 INFO: checking Analysis
23316 INFO: building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc non existent
23316 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
23722 INFO: Analyzing /Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/_pyi_bootstrap.py
23928 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
24125 INFO: Processing hook hook-site
24585 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
25187 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
25279 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
25914 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
26862 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
27567 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
29801 INFO: Processing hook hook-pydoc
33156 INFO: Processing hook hook-email
34289 INFO: Processing hook hook-httplib
35417 INFO: Processing hook hook-email.message
39996 INFO: Analyzing /Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py
40076 INFO: Analyzing /Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_archive.py
40142 INFO: Analyzing /Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_carchive.py
40207 INFO: Analyzing /Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_os_path.py
40246 INFO: Analyzing NCTSU.py
41309 INFO: Hidden import 'codecs' has been found otherwise
41310 INFO: Hidden import 'encodings' has been found otherwise
41310 INFO: Looking for run-time hooks
43156 INFO: Using Python library /Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/Python
43211 INFO: Warnings written to /Users/robertclement/Dropbox/Code/python/NCTSutil/build/NCTSU/warnNCTSU.txt
43227 INFO: checking PYZ
43227 INFO: rebuilding out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing
43227 INFO: building PYZ (ZlibArchive) out00-PYZ.toc
54668 INFO: checking PKG
54668 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
54668 INFO: building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/pyinstaller", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/main.py", line 88, in run
    run_build(opts, spec_file, pyi_config)
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/main.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.build.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **opts.__dict__)
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1924, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1873, in build
    execfile(spec)
  File "/Users/robertclement/Dropbox/Code/python/NCTSutil/NCTSU.spec", line 15, in <module>
    console=True )
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1170, in __init__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1008, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 309, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1069, in assemble
    archive.build(self.name, mytoc)
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_archive.py", line 217, in build
    self._finalize()
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_carchive.py", line 191, in _finalize
    self.save_cookie(toc_pos)
  File "/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_carchive.py", line 367, in save_cookie
    tocpos, self.toclen, pyvers, self._pylib_name)
struct.error: argument for 's' must be a string
```

This also produces the following warnings file in the build folder:

```
W: no module named _subprocess (conditional import by subprocess)
W: no module named _dummy_threading (top-level import by dummy_threading)
W: no module named cl (delayed, conditional import by aifc)
W: no module named _sha (delayed, conditional import by hashlib)
W: no module named nt (conditional import by pyi_os_path)
W: no module named nt (conditional import by __main__)
W: no module named org (top-level import by pickle)
W: no module named _sha512 (delayed, conditional import by hashlib)
W: no module named msvcrt (conditional import by getpass)
W: no module named _sha256 (delayed, conditional import by hashlib)
W: no module named org (top-level import by copy)
W: no module named _md5 (delayed, conditional import by hashlib)
W: no module named msvcrt (conditional import by subprocess)
W: no module named msvcrt (delayed import by getpass)
W: no module named NCTSutil (top-level import by __main__)
W: no module named cl (delayed import by aifc)
W: no module named OverrideFrom23 (top-level import by Carbon.Res)
W: no module named _emx_link (conditional import by os)
W: no module named rourl2path (conditional import by urllib)
W: no module named _winreg (top-level import by mimetypes)
W: no module named SOCKS (top-level import by ftplib)
W: no module named _winreg (delayed import by urllib)
W: no module named nt (top-level import by ntpath)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - pyi_archive (/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_archive.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - dummy_threading (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/dummy_threading.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - bdb (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/bdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - bdb (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/bdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - bdb (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/bdb.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - optparse (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/optparse.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - doctest (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/doctest.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - doctest (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/doctest.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - doctest (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/doctest.pyc)
W: top-level  exec statement detected at line 0 - aetypes (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/aetypes.pyc)
W: top-level  exec statement detected at line 0 - aetypes (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/aetypes.pyc)
W: top-level  exec statement detected at line 0 - aetypes (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/aetypes.pyc)
W: top-level  exec statement detected at line 0 - aetypes (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/aetypes.pyc)
W: top-level  exec statement detected at line 0 - aetypes (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/aetypes.pyc)
W: top-level  exec statement detected at line 0 - aetypes (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/aetypes.pyc)
W: top-level  exec statement detected at line 0 - aetypes (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/aetypes.pyc)
W: top-level  exec statement detected at line 0 - aetypes (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/aetypes.pyc)
W: top-level  exec statement detected at line 0 - aetypes (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/aetypes.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - tokenize (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/tokenize.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - tokenize (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/tokenize.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - aepack (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/aepack.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - aepack (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/aepack.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - pickle (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - pickle (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc)
W: delayed conditional eval hack detected at line 0 - StdSuites (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/StdSuites/__init__.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - encodings (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc)
W: delayed conditional eval hack detected at line 0 - Finder (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages/Finder/__init__.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - pydoc (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pydoc.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - pydoc (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pydoc.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - dis (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/dis.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - hashlib (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/hashlib.pyc)
W: delayed conditional eval hack detected at line 0 - warnings (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - warnings (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc)
W: delayed conditional exec statement detected at line 0 - pyi_importers (/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - email (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/email/__init__.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - wx (/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx/__init__.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - wx (/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx/__init__.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - pdb (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pdb.pyc)
W: delayed conditional eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pdb.pyc)
W: delayed conditional eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pdb.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - pdb (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pdb.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - pkgutil (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - pkgutil (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - collections (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/collections.pyc)
W: delayed  exec statement detected at line 0 - collections (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/collections.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - unittest.main (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - unittest.loader (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.pyc)
W: delayed conditional __import__ hack detected at line 0 - unittest.loader (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.pyc)
W: delayed  __import__ hack detected at line 0 - unittest.loader (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.pyc)
W: __all__ is built strangely at line 0 - __future__ (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/__future__.pyc)
W: delayed  eval hack detected at line 0 - gettext (/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/gettext.pyc)
```

I then modify the .spec file to include a hook for pypubsub and run pyinstaller on the spec file, but the output is almost identical, terminating with the same  "struct.error: argument for 's' must be a string" that 
I got with the initial build.

The path statements in my .profile file include:

```
# Setting PATH for MacPython 2.6
# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Added by Canopy installer on 2015-02-23
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make bashprompt show that     Canopy is active, otherwise 1
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# added by me to see if I could make pyinstaller find dynamic libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib:/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

PATH=$PATH:"/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib":"/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User":"/usr/local/lib/python2.7"
export PATH

PYTHONPATH = "/Users/robertclement/Dropbox/Code/python":"/Users/robertclement/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages":"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages":"/Users/robertclement/Dropbox/Code/python/NCTSutil"
export PYTHONPATH
```

I'm not sure were the unfound modules would be located. If anyone knows where they might be or any other causes of this error I would appreciate knowing the cause.